# Can you share a network connection over two miles?

Tags: networking

Currently, we are currently paying a large sum of money for internet access and telephony that goes to our office just inside of town. We are also paying a large sum of money for internet access and telephony that goes to the workshop where we do the manufacturing. The workshop is located outside of town about 2 miles (1.2 miles as the crow flies) from the office. Unfortunately, there are about three small buildings in the way before it opens up into nice flat, empty farmland, so we don't have a perfectly clear line of sight.

Are there options available which would allow us to share a network connection between the office and the workshop? (It doesn't matter if the workshop's internet speeds end up being a bit slower, and telephony is not required as it can be implemented through systems such as IP Telephony)

Even if the equipment to set up this sort of system is expensive, it would more than pay for itself after a year of paying for two separate internet contracts.

Comment: If you don't have line of site do you have access to a location which you can use that has line of site of both locations?  If so then you can set up a microwave link if local licensing permits. Or you could lay your own cable.

Comment: You will still have to pay a large sum of money for one location to have internet access and telephony.

Comment: @albal Of course, I thought that was given (of course, theoretically you could just use such a system to create a LAN with no "external" internet connection required)

Comment: DO you have 3G Network Access on the both sides?

Comment: @ali786 Yes, but wouldn't that mean we would have to pay for internet plus two additional cell phone bills?

Comment: That will not cost you much you just have to pay for Internet data don't need to pay additional phone bills setup will also be easy... just you need two 3G Dongles.. In which county are you living in, in india we can use 10 GB of data  for a month by just paying 5-10 $...

Comment: Look into the cost of a [leased line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leased_line) between the two sites.  Use HDSL or VDSL to create a network link.

Comment: Many ISPs use username/password authenticated PPPoE to connect users, if you can have your internet lines connected to the same ISP across two buildings you might be able to use the same username/password on both. Have you asked your ISP if they have a solution for you?

You could lay a 2 Mile line, standard ethernet cables support 100 meters, but 100BASE-FX optical fiber ethernet on full duplex can run for 2 kilometers if you just want to run a line between two points. The range is only around 1.2 miles though, you'd have to make a pitstop there and extend the range somehow with another cable